# How to bring the payload stored via mutations

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, vuex4

adding a number using @click event but not working.

Counter.vue

```html
<script>
import { mapState, mapMutations  } from "vuex"
export default {
  data() {
    return{
      //payload
      value: 1,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState(["counter"])
  },
  method: {
    ...mapMutations(["addToCounter"])
  }
}
</script>
```

on main.js

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createStore } from "vuex";

import App from './App.vue';
const store =  createStore({
  state() {
    return {
      counter: 11,
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    addToCounter(state, payload){
      state.counter = state.counter + payload;
    }
  }
})

//connecting store to the application
const app = createApp(App)

//using the store that is created
app.use(store)

app.mount('#app')
```

There is no error but addToCounter isn't working while the value is supposed to be added to the counter when @click is triggered.

[image: When we click + button, the number above should be added]

Comment: My apologies, there is another one to add.h1 class="counter">{{ counter }}</h1>

<button>-</button>

<!--2 way binding part 1-->
        <input 
            type="number"
            v-model="value"
        />
        <!-- value is the payload -->
        <button @click="addToCounter(value)">+</button>
    </div>
</template>

Comment: Feel free to properly edit your question to add this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make an effort in formatting when posting your question.

- It should be `methods` and not `method`.
- What is `main.js`? There is no such file in Nuxt and you should not have to create your own store because it is already baked in: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/store
- `createApp` and `createStore` are related to Vue3, hence not compatible with Vue2 (used by Nuxt as of right now)
- you should not call a vuex mutation to update the state, but rather an action other you could have some issues.

Comment: I am actually trying to follow the guide here. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y7DQhNs9Azw&t=1360s
I believe I need to understand the entire context in Vue3 to make my project working

Comment: Finally it works, it was because of the methods typo.

Comment: Yep, especially don't use Nuxt if you follow a Vue3 tutorial since both are not compatible and there is no benefit here since you're trying to learn Vuex4.

Comment: Noted on the above Kissu. I will definitely put more effort when posting the code.

Comment: Honestly, I am trying to learn Nuxt but there is some syntax that I dont understand and apparently it is coming from Vue which I am learning now. This is the first time I am working on MVC so my apology if I ask so many beginner questions.

Comment: @user16295310 I recommend not mixing a lot of stuff. There is Vue2, Vue3 and Nuxt (using Vue2 only right now). Better to not split your focus and stay on a single one. I recommend learning Vue2 before Vue3 tbh but you can start from Vue3 too. Just be aware of the limitations and the fact that not everything has moved to Vue3 yet. Nuxt is something on top of Vue, but learn the basics and work it a bit before trying Nuxt.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I am trying to familiarize all possible syntax and structure before continue working on my project.